# How to set default value of foreign key pointing to self?

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
     (...)
     leader = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name ='leader_set')
```

And when I create object:

```
Person.objects.create()
```

the value of leader is NULL, which is wrong.

What should I set in default to the same Person object (at start Person is own leader)

I know, that I can add null=True, and after create set leader to fresh created object, but wonder if there's better solution?

```
new_person = Person.objects.create()
new_person.leader = new_person
new_person.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add `blank=True` to that field, because you can't set a FK field until you've got an ID and you don't get an ID until you've saved the object, which as you have seen, you can't do while this field requires a value.

You could then maybe assign this value in a `post_save` method doing something like;

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Person(models.Model):
    leader = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        blank=True
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        related_name ='leader_set'
    )


@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def auto_create_leader(instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Anytime a Person object is created, associate the leader if it's not set
    """
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        if not instance.leader:
            instance.leader = instance
            instance.save(update_fields=['leader',])
```